# Converting a fully lower case / uper case char array back to the user input

Tags: c#, arrays, palindrome

I made a palindrome program on c#. To remove case sensitivity I had to convert the input into lower (or upper) case completely. Now when I am printing the reverse array, I want the case sensitivity to come back. Such as if input = Madam, I want Reverse to be = madaM. Now I know I can make a new char array from the input and I've already done that. But I want to manipulate the LowerInvariant array somehow. I know the Upper method of my code doesn't work because the array is converted into lower case.

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Palindrome
 {
   public static void Main(string [] args)
   {
      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      string lower = input.ToLowerInvariant();
      char[] array = lower.ToCharArray();
      Array.Reverse(array);
      Upper(array, input);
      Console.WriteLine("\nPalindrome: {0}", array.SequenceEqual(lower));
      Console.ReadKey();
   }

   public static void Upper(char[] array, string input)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      {
         if (Input's [i] char is Upper) => Not sure how to put this as a code.
            array[i] = Char.ToUpper(array[i]);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Reverse array :");
      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `Upper` method doesn't look like it's doing what you want - you're saying "If the character is already upper case, make it upper case" - surely that's not what you want.

Comment: Why don't you reverse the input string?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for that I forgot to edit it. And in the if statement I want the compiler to see if that character in the loop is upper in input or not.. Ofcourse that's not what I did in the code, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Why not just use `Console.WriteLine(String.Reverse())`? Too simple?

Comment: @LeffeBrune i'm not sure how that would help, could you explain a bit please?

Comment: "To remove case sensitivity I had to convert the input into lower (or upper) case completely." what case sensitivity? You are just reversing a string? You aren't even actually checking to see if it really is a palindrome.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yeah, he is, with the `array.SequenceEqual(lower)`. Without normalizing the case, the sequence wouldn't be equal when checking `Madam` against `madaM`.

Comment: @MattBurland what I meant was that if the user inputs Pop, it would show as palindrome. If I hadn't converted into lower case, the program would have shown it isn't a palindrome. And I used .SequenceEqual() to check palindrome.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that should do the work! Thanks. :)
But I was challenged by a friend to change the lower case array back into exact reverse input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
public static void Upper(char[] array, string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse array :");
    Console.Write(new string(input.AsEnumerable().Reverse().ToArray()));
}
```

Rather than worrying about the lowercased array, you can simply reverse the original input and make a new string out of the reversed characters.

Comment: What's the point in the `array` parameter if it's not being used?

Comment: @DrewKennedy: There is none. I just wanted to provide a minimal code change that will work. The OP can rename and refactor to his heart's content. :-)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks! :) 
But is there a way to do this with using the array?

Comment: How's that different from Conso≤.WriteL∈e(Str∈g.Reverse())Console.WriteLine(String.Reverse())? There's no point in calling ToEνmerab≤()ToEnumerable(), because the Str∈gString class already implements IEνmerab≤<char>IEnumerable<char>. And anyway, what is the point in converting a string to a char array and then constructing a new string from it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I'm getting some weird character encoding in your comment, but I think I understand your question. You could omit the `.AsEnumerable()`, as you say. `.Reverse()`, however, doesn't return a `String`, but rather an `IEnumerable<char>` in this case. You could technically pass the `char[]` from the `.ToArray()` call directly to the `.Write()` method, but there are overloads that would behave differently if you give them `(string, int, int)` versus `(char[], int, int)`. I feel safer converting it to a `string`.